# Applying pseudo-inverse give unwanted result

Tags: numpy, python-3.9

I have to apply inversion to the equation DX=G.

solving for the equationis not simple as X=D<sup>-1</sup>G, This is because the D matrix is **not** a square matix. So I have to do the matix calculation as X=(D<sup>T</sup>D)<sup>-1</sup>(D<sup>T</sup>G) pseudo inverse.

I wrote the code for this as,

```
X=np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(np.transpose(D),D)),np.matmul(np.transpose(D),G))
```

but this is giving me unwanted results with random noise at the output [image1 unwrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfOeI.jpg), at the same time while employing the following code,

```
X=np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(D),D),np.matmul(np.transpose(D),G))
```

ie., removing the inverse X=(D<sup>T</sup>D)(D<sup>T</sup>G) is giving the kind of desired result which is smooth [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qausr.png), what is happening???? Is there something that I should take care of.

Comment: It's not immediately apparent what the problem is, because it's also not clear what it _should_ look like. Phrases "random errors" and "kind of desired result" aren't really  measurable, making it hard to help. One important consideration is that the matrix inverse is a numerically unstable operation; could be contributing. Still, as it stands, it's not clear what the question is

Comment: You could be dealing with numerical instabilities. Numpy also has a function that computes the pseudo inverse for you: `np.linalg.pinv`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html which may work better

Comment: I have applied np.linalg.pinv and yet the results are the same.My doubt is, if the input data is having errors it should reflect in both the cases, why does actual implementation of pseudo inverse gives random noise while the other gives output with less noise. This is making it difficult to actually draw any conclusion about the input data and i have no other way to verify. @Chrysophylaxs

Comment: In ideal case the expected output is like in the second senario-image2, but it is without taking inverse so mathematically it is incorrect. By saying this I am implying "this what we expect" and there is no solid ground on which I am able to classify what is correct and what is wrong. All this is because the input data is from Experiment, so the phrases"random errors"(random noise) and "kind of desired result" are the only words I can say. To make things short a mistep in the mathematics is giving required result, how so?@AryaMcCarthy